# recall component to render on pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand the logic here. This block of code is for pagination, when it's click it will fire this function.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const { location } = this.context;
    const { query } = this;
    if (!isEqual(query, location.query)) {
        this.query = clone(location.query);
        API.fetchAll( assign({}, query, {
            offset  : this.getOffset(),
            limit   : page
        }) );
    }
}
```

But guessing I really can't tell what it does, do you guys have any clue?

Answer (score 1):

This method is executed when your component receives new state or new props.

It's taking the location property from `this.context` (so `this.context.location`) and query property from `this` (so `this.query`).

If query from `this` is different then location's query - probably becasue location has changed (there is not enough info in the code but I'm guessing URL has changed) you're assigning the new location's query to `this.query`.

When query property is updated you are doing an API call for new resources.

The `assign` method in `fetchAll` is probably from `Object.assign`. So you are creating new object with property query, offset and page.

Comment: why is there a `this.query = clone(location.query);`?

Comment: I don't know from where you are taking `clone` but most likely it's copying location properties to query object. Check out the docs for jQuery clone - https://api.jquery.com/clone/ . I'm not saying it's the same but may do similar things.